# Can't write file into folder with right user, right group and chmod 777

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

So, here is the deal: I got a CentOS server for a new project which runs on Apache. The root of the project (/var/www/html) contains a bunch of folders. Between these folders are one folder named **cache** (used to keep files generated by PHP and by tools like LESS) and another one named **uploads** (used to keep files sent by system users).

Files sent to **uploads** are been saved correctly, without any trouble. But PHP aren't able to to write to the **cache** folder.

We did this:

1. Set the permissions to 0777 with **chmod**.
2. Set the user to the same user who's writing to the uploads folder with **chown**.
3. Set the group to the same group as the user on step 2 with **chgrp**.

We also tried step 3 with other users and groups, including **root** and **apache**.

Nothing worked.

So we tried to to use the **--reference** param with **chmod**, **chown** and **chgrp**, so we could have the configuration for **cache** folder matching the **uploads** one.

We tried logging out and reseting the entire server to make sure the configs were making effect.

It didn't worked too.

We ended up creating a new **cache** folder **INSIDE** of **uploads** and moving it to the original **cache** folder location and... BOOM: Apache was able to write to that folder.

Anyone has any idea of what we could be missing? Is there another config responsible for allowing/forbidden writing to a folder?

Comment: Is it possible there were already files in your cache directory with the same name as those you were trying to save?  Unless you `chmod -R` and `chown -R` you wouldn't be allowing existing files to be overwritten.

Comment: Hey @GentlemanMax! The file names were different and we used -R with all commands.

Comment: Could be the `selinux` permission. Can you post the result of `ls -lZ /var/www/html` ?

Comment: Hey @iamauser, thanks for the tip! The problem was the security context indeed. The following command solved the issue:

chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/folder